# Installing java.xml.bind and Contiki-ng

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, java

I'm trying to install a program called Contiki-NG onto a Ubuntu build sitting in VMware on a Windows 10 station. In the process, I need to build an app called Cooja. I'm getting the following results:

```
icook@ubuntu:~/contiki-ng/tools/cooja$ sudo ant run

Buildfile: /home/icook/contiki-ng/tools/cooja/build.xml

init:

compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/icook/contiki-ng/tools/cooja/build
    [javac] Compiling 170 source files to /home/icook/contiki-ng/tools/cooja/build
    [javac] /home/icook/contiki-ng/tools/cooja/java/org/contikios/cooja/contikimote/interfaces/ContikiEEPROM.java:41: error: package javax.xml.bind does not exist
    [javac] import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
    [javac]                      ^
    [javac] /home/icook/contiki-ng/tools/cooja/java/org/contikios/cooja/contikimote/interfaces/ContikiEEPROM.java:281: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]       element.setText(DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(getEEPROMData()));
    [javac]                       ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable DatatypeConverter
    [javac]   location: class ContikiEEPROM
    [javac] /home/icook/contiki-ng/tools/cooja/java/org/contikios/cooja/contikimote/interfaces/ContikiEEPROM.java:290: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]           setEEPROMData(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(element.getText()));
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable DatatypeConverter
    [javac]   location: class ContikiEEPROM
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 3 errors

BUILD FAILED
/home/icook/contiki-ng/tools/cooja/build.xml:77: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 4 seconds
```

I did a search on the internet, and Stackexchange has the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j

Saying that in Java 11, which I have, shows that I would need to include my own copy of Java EE APIs in the class or module path. My question is, where is the class or module path? How do I add dependencies? There are two other errors in this as well "cannot find symbol", any thoughts on how to solve these?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: did you manage to resolve this? I got the exact same errors as you did!